# I own a Aquila box 3D printer and I'm trying to remove the tube, but the bolt is stuck

Tags: aquila-x3

I finally decided to go to the Internet with this question, recently I used a very bad filament and it broke inside of my Bowden tube. I'm trying to replace the tube in order to get the filament out but the bolt keeping it down just won't seem to unscrew. I really really need help

Comment: please show a photo of the stuck bolt. The printer is rare enough that we can't estimate difficulty or order of operation and we have no idea which bolt you speak of.

Comment: Please add additional information on where it exactly is located and provide images or photos to further build this question. Otherwise we have to close this question. Please take the [tour] and read the [help] to understand what this site is all about.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Aquila X3 uses the same standard pneumatic fittings as most printers for its bowden tubes. In that case you don't need to unscrew anything. You push the plastic collar on the fitting into the metal part of the fitting, and while holding it pushed in you pull the bowden tube out. There are small teeth in there that will disengage allowing the tube to be pulled out. There are small teeth inside the fitting that grip the tube, and retract when pushed by the collar.

If you repeat this a couple times, trim a couple mm off the end of the tube as the damage from the teeth will accumulate. Also, these fittings and their teeth mechanism are rather flimsy so they break easily. In this case you'll need a more destructive approach (likely cut the bowden then use force to unscrew the fitting, praying not to break the extruder, then replace it with a new one, they cost pennies.)